# Jquery date picker - date format issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the Jquery date picker to select a date. When I select a date the format of the date in the textbox is mm-dd-yyyy and I would like dd-mm-yyyy.

**Textbox**

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
});
```

If I then adapt the text box by including a default date:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>" id="datepicker" />
```

The default date appears as I would like in the input box ie dd/mm/yy, but when I open the date picker it takes this date as mm/dd/yy and therefore opens the date picker on the wrong date.

The text box and the picker do not seem to thinking in the same format. How do I correct this?

UPDATE

The issue is now:

1 - when I open the page the default date in textbox is correct and in the right format dd/mm/yy

2 - when I open the date picker the date picker goes to the correct date ie the default date

3 - when I then choose a date from the date picker the format reverts to mm/dd/yy in the text box

Does, when using JQuery to update an id, the format of the text box get bypassed in some way?

Comment: `constrainInput: true`

Comment: I [can't replicate that](http://jsbin.com/ONeNAHA/1/edit), perhaps you could put together a [minimal, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem and post it to http://jsbin.com or http:/jsfiddle.net. **Edit**: Ah, but I was using `type="text"`, as in your HTML snippet.

Comment: Some browsers are rendering the [`type="date"`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date) if supported. This is screwing up the jQueryUI datepicker initialization I think.

Comment: @ Richard: You first snippet uses `type="text"`, your second uses `type="date"`. Please edit the question to make them consistent, reflecting what you're actually using.

Comment: I appreciate all the comments and help. The type="text" or type="date" does not appear to make any difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

You've actually changed the `type` attribute of your input box to a `date`. Keep it as text and it should be fine:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>" id="datepicker" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one specific for your code:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

More general info available here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate